# In iOS, how do I auto-correct the last word upon submit?

Tags: ios, autocomplete, chat, autocorrect

On my iOS app's chat screen, words get auto-corrected after the user enters a space. But the last word does not get auto-corrected when the user taps Send. How can I get the suggested word to replace the misspelled word when the user taps Send?

Answer (score 4):

The last solution forces you to hide your keyboard. I found a solution that autocorrects the last word without resigning the keyboard by adding a space at the end before submitting:

```
// This will force the autocompletion to take effect
text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", text];

// Remove the last character afterwards
text = [text substringToIndex:[text length]-1];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call `resignFirstResponder` on your text field as the first action after pressing send, it will accept the correction before sending.

```
- (IBAction)sendButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    // Send the textfield's text
}
```

Comment: I find it better to use `[self.view endEditing:YES]` instead of `resignFirstResponder`. It's much easier when there is more than one text field and/or text view.

Comment: @rmaddy I use that too, but this answers the question more directly without needing additional knowledge. The OP just mentioned one field, so I figured I'd keep it simple.